# Can't use pen to navigate in viewport

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

When I middle click, as soon as the pen is in hover distance, the blender viewport starts to rotate, and if I were to try to rotate again, the rotation will snap depending on where on the screen I put my pen.

I want it to behave like when I touch the pen to the surface, it starts to rotate as I move the mouse from that position and when I take the pen off, the rotation stops. But basically anytime I have middle mouse down even without touching the screen, it rotates wildly. The same is true if Im trying to zoom or pan.

Also, the emulate middle mouse button doesn't do anything.

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **emulate middle-mouse** button does not directly navigate for you when you use the pen, rather it adds a key or keys that in combination with the pen touching and moving navigate like with the mouse.

In that regard, once activated, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button held down will be used to rotate with the pen like you would with the <kbd>MMB</kbd>.

If you use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, you can pan the screen like you would with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd>.

And using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> gives your pen the zoom based on moving up or down movement like you would normally do with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd>.

As you can see, the emulation essentially replaces the <kbd>MMB</kbd> with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. So some other functions like loop select that would normally use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>, will have other keys like a double <kbd>LMB</kbd>(click).

Happy Blending.

Comment: awesome, that works! thanks!